# Looking for the best place to insert into a vector

Tags: c++, vector

For example if I have a vector of ints

```
 vector<int> my_vector;

 my_vector[0] = 6;
 my_vector[1] = 3;
```

So my vector is of size 2 right now.

Now let's say I want to add another integer in my vector. Let's just say this new integer is 10.

I want to be able to set it up 3 (my_vec.size() + 1) ways. In other words, check where placing my new value in my vector of ints would result in the value I'm interested in.

**10**, 6, 3

6, **10**, 3

6, 3, **10**

Out of those 3 options, I'll pick the one that best fits my needs. The one I pick, will be my new vector. So if I pick 6, 10, 3, that will be my vector afterwards.

That's the gist of what I want to be able to do.

I have a very inefficient brute force way of creating temp vectors and calculating it that way. I was wondering if there is a simple and optimal way to go about this. I essentially want to be able to compute a new value that I want to add into my vector in all possible areas and look for whatever value I'm interested in.

Comment: What online quiz web site is this from? Just curious.

Comment: So... you want the least element to occupy the first position. Is the answer obvious now?

Comment: It's not from an online quiz. I'm actually trying to use this for making my heuristic for TSP. Basically after having 2 nodes, I want to be able to take another node and figure out where best to insert into my vector of nodes that results in the smallest cost until there are no nodes left

Comment: The example was merely an example. I'm not interested in the subtraction part. I just want to be able to know where to insert into a vector for a more complicated problem

Comment: So your brute-force method has a formula which scores each configuration? There's an elegant way to use `std::sort` lurking here, I'm sure, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Why do you need to insert the number into the vector to calculate the value? I think the better way is to calculate the targeted value with inserting.

Comment: is there any logic in the order your elements are in the array before you insert your element??

Comment: `vector[0] = 6;` is undefined behaviour due to out of range access; you need to explicitly grow the vector to change its size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert new element to the end (most efficient way for the vector) and then move it to the front step by step and test each combination:

```
 vec.push_back( new_value );
 test_vector( vec );
 for( size_t i = vec.size() - 1; i > 0; --i ) {
      std::swap( vec[i], vec[i-1] );
      test_vector( vec );
 }
```

live example on [ideone](http://ideone.com/UD2GVa) for 6,3 + 10. New element will always end at the first position. You need to find best position and then move your element there, that should be pretty obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I understand your question.
Your computing method is complex. It is a example just now.
Only can you pick a kind of arrangement?
You can implement a function like this:

```
int GetArrangemnetValue(vector<int>& sourceVec, int nNewPos, int nNewValue);
```

This function to simulate a whole vetor.
You can do some compute is this function.
Then you can do some select via the return value of funtion.

So you can use this function and not a temporary vector.

Comment: Please provide more details. I have a little puzzle for your question.

Answer (score 0):

You really only have 2 cases here. First case: the newly added number is less than the first number in the vector. In this case the number should always be added to the beginning of the vector. If the new number is larger, it should always go in the second spot in the vector (since moving it any farther down the vector will not affect the new total).